# Canvas : Find corners of a card in Image

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas

My goal is to extract any card from an image..

Description:

I have the following image initially...

[image: Original Image]

Drew it on a canvas and applied canny edge detection and got this..

[image: Image after Canny Edge Detection]

The result I wish to get should be somethig similar to :

[image: required output]

To extract the card out of the image I need to find the corners of the card.

OR

Another way which I found on the internet is :

1. Loop through all the edges and find the closed ones, then
2. Find the largest closed edge and crop accordingly.

But I am getting clueless while trying to build any logic to implement any of the method.

Did this to get the edge detection, and am unable to proceed further :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "bcard.png";
img.onload = function() {
    var canv = document.getElementById("canv");
    var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
    canv.height = img.height;
    canv.width = img.width;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    window.canny = CannyJS.canny(canv); //included a js script to do canny edge detection
    canny.drawOn(canv);
```

}

Comment: Include the code what you have tried. Images won't help!!

Comment: @Pugazh  After getting edge detection I am unable to guess any approach to go further..

Answer (score 3):

First, I extracted the *red channel* from the image provided.

**Red channel image:**

[image]

Next I blurred it applying a *Gaussian blur*.

**Blurred image:**

[image]

Finally, I performed edge detection to obtain the following.

**Final edge:**

[image]

In order to crop the card perfectly you will have to find only **ONE** external contour. To do that you have **dilate** the resulting image

**Dilated image:**

[image]

Now you have to find contours. Find the external contours present. In this case, you will find only one contour. Draw a bounding rectangle around this contour.

[image]

Using the coordinates of the bounding rectangle, **crop** the image:

[image]

(I have the resulting script in python, but I see you have scripted the code in javascript)

Comment: @SauravPradhan Chose the appropriate kernel size for blurring before finding edges. In this case I used a kernel size of 5

Comment: Can you please share the code of extracting red channel fro the image, that you used in python  @Jeru Luke

Comment: @JeruLuke can you share the Python source code to achieve this result? Thank you very much.